# Using Java to do *resumable uploads* using a *signed url* on google cloud storage

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Based on  the doc regarding how to create an object in google-cloud-storage (see "create" method in https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/index.html), we should be using the blob.writer(...) method when trying to upload large files, as it presumably somehow automatically handles resumable uploads. Is this right?

However, if we wish to do resumable uploads on SIGNED urls, how does one do so in Java? (Any sample code or pointers would be very much appreciated; thus far, my research has led me to believe that it is not possible using the nicely created java libraries, and instead one needs to custom build one's own logic using "PUT" and "POST" statements in Java after one has generated the signed url. Is this the "best" way so far?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your first point, yes, the `blob.writer(...)` method does automatically handle resumable uploads. Unfortunately, this method is not callable from a signed URL, and only uploads files directly from a stream of bytes.

However, as you mentioned, it is possible to create a resumable upload from a signed URL with other methods, for instance using a `PUT` method seems to be a nice workaround.

What I did, was the following:

1. Create a [signed URL](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/index.html) with a "PUT" method. You can do so by specifying the [SignUrlOption](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.SignUrlOption.html), as well I specified a service account with the required permissions in the bucket.
2. Use [URLFetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests) to throw an HTTP request to this signed URL. I believe that you cannot use a curl command directly for example, and the UrlFetch API does the trick.
3. Add the uploadType=resumable header to the `urlFetch` HTTP request. See [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#start-resumable) on how this works, and extra parameters and information.
4. I configured `URLFetch` to do an asynchronous call to the signed URL, as I believe it's more convenient when uploading big files.

An example code, to be used in an App Engine handler:

```
package com.example.storage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

// Cloud Storage Imports
import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BucketInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.SignUrlOption;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.storage.HttpMethod;

// Url Fetch imports
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod;
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest;
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService;
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader;

@WebServlet(name = "MainStorage", value = "/")
public class MainStorage extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
                // Bucket parameters 
                String bucketName = "MY-BUCKET-NAME";
                String blobName = "MY-BLOB-NAME";
                String keyPath = "/PATH-TO-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-KEY/key.json";

                BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, blobName);
                Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

                // Create signed URL with SignUrlOptions
                URL signedUrl = storage.signUrl(BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, blobName).build(), 14, TimeUnit.DAYS,
                                                SignUrlOption.signWith(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(keyPath))),
                                                SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT));

                // Contents to upload to the Blob
                String content = "My-File-contents";

                // Build UrlFetch request
                HTTPRequest upload_request = new HTTPRequest(signedUrl, HTTPMethod.PUT);
                upload_request.setPayload(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                // Set request to have an uploadType=resumable
                HTTPHeader set_resumable = new HTTPHeader("uploadType", "resumable");
                upload_request.setHeader(set_resumable);
                URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();

                // Do an asynchronous call to the signed URL with the contents
                fetcher.fetchAsync(upload_request);

                // Return response to App Engine handler call
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.getWriter().println("Hello Storage");
        }
}
```

This can probably be done in a better way, but I believe it gives an idea on how such application can be made.

Comment: ok, so if the internet connection breaks temporarily, the above code will "automatically" handle it (due to "resumable" being set?) (Also, if I'm not using GAE, I presume I drop the "fetcher" and instead just use the normal HttpURLConnection? (If so, how would HttpUrlConnection be asynchronous as I didn't see any such method in the javadocs for HttpUrlConnection).

Comment: No, the previous code just creates the resumable session request. [This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#resume-upload) explains how to check if the session has been interrumped or not, and how to recover it (you do so by sending a request to the same session URL you created previously, a 200-201 response means it has ended correctly, 308 means it is incomplete). Regarding what library to use instead of UrlFetch, any REST java library can be used. I onlyused an async method because handlers in App Engine have timeouts, it's not necessary

Comment: I have found [this library](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) in Java that processes asynchronous HTTP calls, there are probably more examples out there

Comment: In case you want to user curl with the signedUrl: use the String of signedUrl.toExternalForm()